# Can extract_numeric deal with negative numbers?

Tags: r, tidyr

Is there a way to use tidyr's extract_numeric() to extract negative numbers?

For example,

```
> extract_numeric("2%")
[1] 2
> extract_numeric("-2%")
[1] 2
```

I'd really like the second call to return -2.

Bill

PS: While it doesn't concern me today, I suspect cases such as "-$2.00" complicate any general solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`extract_numeric` is pretty simple:

```
> extract_numeric
function (x) 
{
    as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9.]+", "", as.character(x)))
}
<environment: namespace:tidyr>
```

It just replaces any char that isn't 0 to 9 or "." with nothing. So "-1" will become 1, and there's nothing you can do about it... except maybe file an enhancement request to tidyr, or write your own...

```
extract_num = function(x){as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9\\-]+","",as.character(x)))}
```

will sort of do it:

```
> extract_num("-$1200")
[1] -1200
> extract_num("$-1200")
[1] -1200
> extract_num("1-1200")
[1] NA
Warning message:
In extract_num("1-1200") : NAs introduced by coercion
```

but a regexp could probably do better, only allowing minus signs at the start...

Comment: I suppose it depends on if you want to evaluate the result as an expression or not. Using `eval(parse())` on the gsubbed string would return a number. Otherwise regexp would be the way to go.

Comment: As Spacedman says, both his and Sven's solutions give the same answer in many cases, so picking one was largely a coin flip.  I did pick this one because it seemed to do what I need and to flag non-obvious cases by producing NA. Thanks!

Comment: Could you file a bug or pull request on tidyr? Please?

Comment: issue filed on github.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `sub` if there's a single number in the string. Here's an approach:

The function:

```
myfun <- function(s) as.numeric(sub(".*?([-+]?\\d*\\.?\\d+).*", "\\1", s))
```

Examples:

```
> myfun("-2%")
[1] -2
> myfun("abc 2.3 xyz")
[1] 2.3
> myfun("S+3.")
[1] 3
> myfun(".5PPP")
[1] 0.5
```

Comment: Note extract_numeric, your solution, and my solution all give different answers on "1-2-1234". You pays your money and you takes your choice...

Comment: @Spacedman Of course our functions give different results for this example. As I said, mine is intended to be used for strings with a single number.